# Button stripe background using css3 background

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a button with this type of background

[image: Demo Image]

I am only referring to weekly activity button.

I want to accomplish it using css only, So that I can customize the gradient, border etc for several other buttons.

The button is having a linear gradient, inner and outer box shadow and stripe on the right side.

I am not asking for actual code. I am just looking for any reference which I can refer to do this.

Till now I have done some basic gradient and background stuff on buttons but this seems to be much advanced.

Regards

EDIT:
I am looking for some advanced reference guide which I can refer, preferable video tutorials so that I can understand the concept.
I am new to UI and mostly work on server side.

Comment: Link above is **almost entirely** what you're describing. (top two answers hold your answer :P)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

You can view this page to learn gradients in CSS3...

Comment: The only was deleted by the answerer, I was about to accept the answer. Anyway really appreciated the effort by the answerer.

Comment: @Syed I undeleted it. I just thought it wasn't what you were looking for. I think chipChocolate.py's response may be closer to what you're thinking.

Comment: @0x24a537r9 can you do something about right side tilt bar.
I started looking at the w3schools tutorials for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). After just a minute of playing with it I got [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9pthdq/). The gradient code:

```
background: rgb(90,175,244); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(90,175,244,1) 0%, rgba(30,87,153,1) 55%, rgba(50,14,81,1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(90,175,244,1)), color-stop(55%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(75%,rgba(50,14,81,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(90,175,244,1) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 55%,rgba(50,14,81,1) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(90,175,244,1) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 55%,rgba(50,14,81,1) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(90,175,244,1) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 55%,rgba(50,14,81,1) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(90,175,244,1) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 55%,rgba(50,14,81,1) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5aaff4', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

... which replicates that gradient decently well.

Comment: @0x24a537r9 I have already looked at that. My question is not about code. I want to understand the advanced concepts of css backgrounds and gradient. For example triangle after:pseudo element etc etc